# transfer authenticated user between native and web javascript

Tags: authentication, cordova, parse-platform

I am using parse.com and phonegap, and want to be able to pass user credentials between the native and phonegap/uiwebview part of the app.

I have a valid PFUser in the native side, and want to pass/create the same valid user to the web portion of the app.

Can a user be created using existing credentials, maybe Parse.User.current()._sessionToken?

Comment: You should check out Ray Camden's series of posts on Parse.com and PhoneGap. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/10/31/Adding-Parsecom-User-support-to-your-PhoneGap-application?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RaymondCamdensColdfusionBlog+%28Raymond+Camden%27s+ColdFusion+Blog%29

Comment: Thanks, I have read his blog, and he even mentions, in the future he might answer my question.  But that does not answer how I can take a native user and pass it back to the PG app.  Thanks tho!

Comment: Is there a generic way to pass data between webview and native on PG? If so, why not just let the native be a proxy for the webview (or vice versa)?

Comment: @user94154 - yes that is an option, but of course that would mean re-writing it native for each platform.  Would like to skip that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a sessionToken and a User's objectId, you have all the information you should need to re-login a User on the JavaScript side.  However, there is no supported method to do it.  You would have to do something terrible like:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.id = "the object id";
user._sessionToken = "the session token";
Parse.User._saveCurrentUser(user);
user.fetch({
  success: function(user) {
    // Now the user is logged in.
  }
});
```

However, this is unsupported, may not work, probably will break in the future, and may burst into flames at any moment.  So don't do it. ;-)